# Create custom field in SELECT if other field is null

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a seemingly simple thing to do but I can't find any reference to it. I want to add a customized field to my select statement if the value of another field is null. In the below I want to create a field named 'IMPACT' that shows a value of 'Y' if the LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID field in the subquery is null. How do I do this?

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME, IMPACT = IF LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE ''
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.FIRST_NAME,
A.LAST_NAME,
B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,
A.ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME
FROM ACTIVE_ACCOUNTS A,
QL_ASSETS B
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID(+)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CASE` instead of `IF`:

```
SELECT 
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END AS IMPACT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.FIRST_NAME,
        A.LAST_NAME,
        B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,
        A.ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME
    FROM ACTIVE_ACCOUNTS A,
    QL_ASSETS B
    WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID(+)
```

You should also use LEFT JOIN syntax instead of the old (+) syntax (but that's more of a style choice in this case - it does not change the result):

```
SELECT 
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END AS IMPACT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.FIRST_NAME,
        A.LAST_NAME,
        B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,
        A.ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME
    FROM ACTIVE_ACCOUNTS A
    LEFT JOIN QL_ASSETS B
        ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID
     )
```

In fact, since you aren't *using* any of the columns from `B` in your result (only checking for *existence*) you can just use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME, 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                     FROM QL_ASSETS 
                     WHERE LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID = A.ACCOUNT_ID)
         THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE '' 
         END AS IMPACT
    FROM ACTIVE_ACCOUNTS A
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) statement:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,
  LAST_NAME,
  ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME,
  CASE WHEN Location_Account_ID IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END AS IMPACT
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT A.FIRST_NAME,
    A.LAST_NAME,
    B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,
    A.ULTIMATE_PARENT_NAME
  FROM ACTIVE_ACCOUNTS A,
    QL_ASSETS B
  WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID(+)
  ) a
```

p.s. also added a alias for your derived table so you wont get an error for that.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't exactly get what you were asking based on your following statement

> (that shows a value of 'Y' if the LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID field in the
>   subquery is null)

I can suggest that you use an expression.

Put this statement in between your expression.

`NVL(B.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,'Y') IMPACT`

Comment: I submitted an edit for your answer so that it is readable.  Whilst TXT speak may be appropriate on a text, it isn't appropriate on Stack Overflow.  Please take care when submitting answers so that your answers can be fully understood.